# Track user selected values on ecommerce(amazon.com) website (GAE Python) using Google Analytics API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

I have designed an ecommerce website like amazon.com. I want to collect user analytics data on my website. I am still evaluating options and [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) looks good as it does not charge anything for a good amount of usage. And it should be fast.

What information do I want to collect about user behavior on my website:

1. What "dropdown" menu values do they select(say for narrowing down the exact product category)
2. What "checkboxes" do they select to filter out based on price range, size, type, or a specific feature
3. Which result entries(matched products) on the search page do they click
4. It would be good if I could get the time of day when the above happened
5. Also how long the user viewed a page (with an upper limit for cases when a user opens a tab and forgets to close it)
6. I hope the Google Analytics API has some feature to prepare charts based on the above data, as well as provide the average monthly values for the above counts

I decided to use an external Analytics tool since writing into NDB would take time, increase writes and increase the storage requirement

Any guidance is highly appreciated.. Anyone who has implemented similar analytics for their website, please share your advice..

Comment: RTFM? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: @PeterKnego Thanks Peter for the link. I did go through it before posting the question but i am not confident about it as I have never used it.